# BULK insert with FIRE_TRIGGERS not execute the trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the following code to Bulk insert a CSV file:

```
    BULK
INSERT CustomSelection
FROM 'c:\asd\a1.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW =2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIRE_TRIGGERS
)
GO
```

I have the FIRE_TRIGGERS property but the trigger is still not executing. 
The trigger works for sure because if i manually insert into the table then it executes. Any help to solve that ?

Comment: Is the trigger "INSERT or INSTEAD OF" ?

Comment: As probably you know, your trigger it's supossed to be fired only once for the full set of rows imported. can your trigger handle multiple rows of data?

Comment: Actually i didn't know that. So is it executed at the end of the Bulk insert?.

Comment: Yes, I will elaborate an answer.

Comment: The Insert trigger it's fired just before insert operation. (You can even cancel the insertion inside the trigger)

Comment: Maybe those triggers are disabled. Run this query: `SELECT is_disabled, * FROM sys.triggers WHERE parent_id=OBJECT_ID(N'MySchema.MyTable')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a bulk-import operation, your trigger will be fired only once because  it's considerated as a single statement that affects multiple rows of data.

Your trigger should be able to handle a set of rows instead a single rows. Maybe this is the reason because your manual insert test is working fine and your bulk import is failing.

The C section of this MSDN article, show you how to create an insert trigger to Handle Multiple Rows of Data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx

Hope it helps.