# Databases - ID column - identity or not?

Tags: sql, bulkinsert

I'm did some research about SQL batch inserts - let's say I have 100k items to be inserted, and I set the batch size to 100.

If the ID column is not marked as `Identity` then that bulk insert will work.

But I found quite interesting (theoretical so far) problem, and I need some opinions:

The problem can be, if e.g. 5 users are making the bulk inserts in the same time, how then **safely provide the the ID column value** ? I can't just get the `table rows count + 1`, because in that way all of that 5 users will have the ID duplicates and the bulk insert operation will fail.

Comment: Why not using a GUID instead of a numeric Identifier?

Comment: Have you tried considering here, `TRANSACTION`, rollback and commit can help that issue.

Comment: insert NULL into the identity column it will automatically create a unique id.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SEQUENCE as an UNIQUE ID generator or try TRIGGER ON INSERT to get a unique ID.

EDIT

With mysql you can build trigger for every row

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER adresse_trigger_insert_check
 BEFORE INSERT ON adresse
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF NEW.land IS NULL THEN
  SET NEW.land := 'XY';
 END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ok, but If I make the `before insert trigger`, if will be fired only once, even if I insert many rows http://stackoverflow.com/a/17759742/106616 What now ?

Comment: @tony With mysql you can build "for each row" trigger (look above).

Answer (score 1):

Should I Use IDENTITY or Not?

[Sometimes Another Approach Works Better](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/should-i-use-identity-or-not)