# Bulk Insert with select and procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've been googled about my problem, but I didn't find anything relevant.

I'm executing a Bulk Insert with flag FIRE_TRIGGERS enabled.

So, I need pass each row in my Bulk Insert to a procedure.

When I execute a insert row by row, my triggers works fine but when I execute a Bulk Insert my triggers don't work.

My trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tgSetDetails]
   ON  [PORTALSQLDB].[dbo].[BurnTimeRawData]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ServiceTag varchar(10);
    DECLARE @Platform varchar(50);

    SELECT
        @ServiceTag = ServiceTag,
        @Platform = Platform
    FROM
        inserted

    EXEC spBurnTimeInsertData @ServiceTag, @Platform
END
```

Any idea how I can do this job?

Thanks :)

Comment: Someone has asked the question here, not sure if the answer is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759718/bulk-insert-with-fire-triggers-not-execute-the-trigger Your trigger can only handle one record, not all at once, so it could be the issue.

Comment: @Leonidas199x ok, I know the trigger can only handle one record at time, what I can do about this?

Comment: Write a loop to do it on the data that has been inserted after the bulk insert?

Comment: Is this a one off or on going? If it is a one off, insert the data then write a loop to fire the stored proc with the required details as your trigger does and leave the trigger as is. If this is on going, you will need to either rewrite your trigger, or, look at bulk inserting into a staging table, then from the staging table to your table with the trigger on.

Answer (score 0):

This trigger will fire once for each insert statement or bulk insert batch. To call a proc for each row, you'll need a cursor.

It would be better to refactor the proc code as a set-based operation to include in the trigger code.  That will perform much better.

Comment: Ok, but I already tried to use a cursor, but my table was blocked and any insert was committed. Do you have any example for me?

Comment: Having a **cursor** inside a **trigger** is probably the worst performance sin you can have in SQL Server . A trigger should be *very nimble, small, fast* - it should **NOT** do any heavy lifting or extensive processing, since it runs in the context of the calling code that caused the trigger to fire, and that code won't be able to complete its operation until the trigger is done, too .....

Comment: @JoseFelipeBlumdeAraujo, the set-based approach I mentioned would be best. For specific recommendations on improving performance with the cursor, you'll need to add what you tried to your question along with the DDL for tables, indexes, and proc code. General examples are too broad here.